# How to modify time regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am newbie in Regular Expressions.

I need to check this time 18:00(00:00, 01:00, 05:12, any time of this format) by regexp, is it correct or no.

Here is my variant:

```
/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/
```

Can I change [0-9][0-9] to something like 2*[0-9] ???

Comment: That pattern should match `18:00`. Please provide more patterns you would like to match and any patterns you would like to not match.

Comment: I'd suggest reading [a regex tutorial](http://regular-expressions.info), particularly [one on limiting repetion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: That will match `18:00`. It will also match `99:00`, `00:99`, and `99:99`, which aren't valid 24-hour times. Is this a desired behaviour? (See @npinti's answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specifically want to match `18:00` you should use `/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/`. The answers provided so far will match `aaa12:99ddd`. The `^` and `$` are anchors and will instruct the regex to match specifically the given string.

If you are after a 24 hour validation regular expression you could use this: `/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/` (taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/)).

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it like this: `/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it by adding a repetition clause:

```
/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/
```

But you should add the starting and ending clauses :

```
/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/
```

Comment: In what programming language do you use this regexp?

Comment: I guess it is [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} and not /[0-9{2}]:[0-9]{2}/

Comment: Sry about the spelling, I'm on my mobile